# Android Wear: animation in WatchFace

Tags: android, wear-os, watch-face-api

I would to create an animated WatchFace for Android Wear. 
I've 20 images to add (or to change completely) every X ms to the background.

Now: i've followed [this tutorial](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2014/12/making-performant-watch-face.html) but the animation doesn't start. I see only one of the twenty bitmap over my background:

```
if (isInAmbientMode()) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBackgroundAmbient, SRC, DEST, null);
} else {
       canvas.drawBitmap(mBackground, SRC, DEST, null);
       for (int i = 0; i < LoopBMP.length; i++) {
            canvas.save();

            Bitmap cloud = LoopBMP[i];
            canvas.drawBitmap(cloud,centerX, centerY,null);
            canvas.restore();
       }
 }
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding how the `CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine` does its drawing. I'm guessing that the code snippet you posted is in your `onDraw` method; this method is called **once for each frame** of your animation.

Meaning that you need to move your animation "loop" outside of the `onDraw` method. There are several ways to accomplish this, but I've dummied up one below based on your code.

```
private int i;

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas, Rect bounds) {
    super.onDraw(canvas, bounds);

    // probably other code here

    if (isInAmbientMode()) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBackgroundAmbient, SRC, DEST, null);
    } else {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBackground, SRC, DEST, null);
        if (i < LoopBMP.length) {
            canvas.save();
            Bitmap cloud = LoopBMP[i];
            canvas.drawBitmap(cloud,centerX, centerY,null);
            canvas.restore();
            i++;
            // probably want an X-ms delay here to time the animation
            invalidate();
        } else {
            i = 0;
        }
    }

    // probably other code here
}
```

Note that this is a snippet I just threw together to demonstrate what I'm talking about; it's by no means ready-to-run. In particular, you will want a delay between frames of your animation; you can implement that with a `Handler` like the one used for the second hand in this sample: http://developer.android.com/samples/WatchFace/Wearable/src/com.example.android.wearable.watchface/AnalogWatchFaceService.html#l117

Comment: Yep, the code is in onDraw(). But I know that I use more code/assignments in onDraw the wearable might consume more battery..